# How to make Popen wait so the command finishes?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

The objective is that a command is launched in a bash shell with Popen, and then the output of this command is passed to a variable, but Popen should wait until the command finishes before moving on, which doesn't happen.

I tried using call instead of Popen, but call doesn't output anything but the exit code, which isn't ideal.
I tried using wait() too, but I get an error.

```
var1 = Popen(["command | grep 'stuff' | cut -d 'delimiter' -f3"], 
             shell=True, stdout=PIPE,
             universal_newlines=True).communicate()[0].rstrip()
var2 = Popen(["command | grep 'stuff' | cut -d 'delimiter' -f1"], 
             shell=True, stdout=PIPE,
             universal_newlines=True).communicate()[0].rstrip()
print(var1 + var2)
```

Python prints var1 correctly, but not var2, which is None because it was not assigned by anything since the command didn't run or wasn't allowed time to finish.
Running the var2 command directly on the terminal, exactly as in the python program, yields the desired results, but when python tries to run it, it simply skips it and prints var1 and var2, but only the var1 string is displayed, var2 is completely ignored.

Comment: Uhh. `communicate()` *always* waits the end of your pipeline, in this case `cut`, to close its stdout; otherwise, it couldn't possibly return a value. This question is based on a false premise.

Comment: Why use a shell pipeline for `grep` and `cut` when you can just do that in Python itself? That would avoid the need for `shell=True` which is pretty much a security bug waiting to happen.

Comment: ...if you have a case where you're going to argue that `Popen()` returns while the pipeline is still running, you're going to need to provide a [mcve] that lets us observe that behaviour ourselves.

Comment: @DanielPryden, *nod*. `shell=True` *could* be used safely, if the OP moved all dynamically-generated arguments out of the argument parsed by the shell as code (`['''somecommand "$1" | grep "$2" | cut''', "_", "this-becomes-$1", "this-becomes-$2"]`, but there's no evidence that they're doing so.

Comment: Charles Duffy there are two Popen and two variables which are assigned by the output of those Popen. After both Popen are run by Python, only the first variable is printed, the other is None

Answer (score 0):

The `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'wait'` error occurs because the `communicate()` method returns a tuple of `(stdout, stderr)` strings. `wait()` is a method on the `Popen` object itself. You don't need to call `wait()` if you use `communicate()`, since it will do the wait for you. And you *can't* call `wait()` on the `Popen` object if you throw away the only reference to it.

That said, do you really need to use `grep` and `cut` to accomplish the job? Something like this is likely going to be faster and less likely to contain a security bug:

```
p = Popen(['command'], stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
result = []
for line in p.stdout:
    if 'stuff' in line:
        value = line.split('delimiter')[4]
        result.append(value)
```

Comment: Everything here is *true*, but I'm hard-pressed to see it as an answer to the OP's problem. (which is to say, that I'm hard-presssed to see the OP's problem as sufficiently well-specified as to be answerable at all at this point).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Agreed, but this is trying to address the second half of the question, the `'str' object has no attribute 'wait'` error.

Comment: Then why python skips Popen? It immediately jumps from the second Popen to the print call, which then prints the first Popen but not the second. And by the way, I tried running the command of the second popen directly on the terminal and it works just fine

Comment: @DonJhoe: There is no `print` in your question at all. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem -- without that, all anyone here can do is guess.

Comment: @DanielPryden refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the command as a string, or parse it into tokens yourself. You'll want to use `subprocess.run` instead of the low-level `Popen`. Trivially

```
var = subprocess.run("command | grep 'stuff' | cut -d 'delimiter' -f3", 
         shell=True, stdout=PIPE,
         universal_newlines=True).stdout
```

A much better solution is to replace `grep` and `cut` with Python code, and get rid of the `shell=True` as a useful bonus.

```
var = list()
output = subprocess.run(["command"], stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
for line in output.stdout.split('\n'):
    if 'stuff' in line:
        var.append(line.split('delimiter')[2])
```

Comment: Everything here is true, but *does it fix the OP's problem* (the one leading to their belief that their program isn't being allowed to complete)? If so, how?

Comment: Good question. I'm vaguely hoping that doing it correctly will remove the symptom.